# Get fiscal year based on current timestamp-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

> > I am trying get the start date of the financial year based on today's date.

So after a little research, I found this package called [`fiscalyear`](https://fiscalyear.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) where you can modify the start date of the fiscal year. In my case i wanted **`01-07-year`** to be the start date of my fiscal year so i set `fiscalyear.START_MONTH = 7`

I have tried the below(reproducible example if you `pip install fiscalyear`):

```
import datetime
import fiscalyear
fiscalyear.START_MONTH = 7
a = fiscalyear.FiscalYear(datetime.datetime.now().year).start.date()
a.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Which outputs correctly:

```
'2018-07-01'
```

However, this would not work when the month turns to August, since the `datetime.datetime.now().year` doesnot change. So i tried doing something like:

```
if (datetime.datetime.now()-pd.to_datetime('2018-07-01')).days < 365:
    a = fiscalyear.FiscalYear(datetime.datetime.now().year).start.date()
    print(a.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
else:
    a = fiscalyear.FiscalYear(datetime.datetime.now().year+1).start.date()
    print(a.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

I have a bad feeling about what I am doing since this might now work for leap years too.

> > Is there some better way to do this in python which will detect the start date of the fiscal year based on current timestamp?

*py version*: `3.6.7`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My knowledge in the fiscal area is somewhere close to **Zero**, but according to [[ReadTheDocs.FiscalYear]: Basic Usage](https://fiscalyear.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html):

> The `FiscalYear` class provides an object for storing information about the start and end of a particular fiscal year.
>
> ...
>
> The start and end of each of the above objects are stored as instances of the `FiscalDateTime` class. This class provides all of the same features as the `datetime` class, with the addition of the ability to query the fiscal year, fiscal quarter, fiscal month, and fiscal day.

So, *FiscalYear* isn't to be used with dates, but *FiscalDateTime* (or its simpler sibling: *FiscalDate*) instead.

> ```py
> >>> import fiscalyear
> >>> fiscalyear.START_MONTH = 7
> >>>
> >>> cur_y = fiscalyear.FiscalYear(datetime.datetime.now().year)
> >>> cur_y.start.date()
> datetime.date(2018, 7, 1)
> >>> cur_y.end.date()
> datetime.date(2019, 6, 30)
> >>>
> >>> cur_dt = fiscalyear.FiscalDate(2019, 2, 19)  # Current date (at answer time)
> >>> cur_dt.fiscal_year
> 2019
> >>>
> >>> jul_dt = fiscalyear.FiscalDate(2019, 7, 19)  # A date past July 1st (when the fiscal year should change)
> >>> jul_dt.fiscal_year
> 2020
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You can try following code, It worked for me:

```
>>> import fiscalyear
>>> fiscalyear.START_MONTH = 4
>>> fiscalyear.FiscalYear.current()
FiscalYear(2021)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) with helper `DatetimeIndex`:

```
r = pd.to_datetime([f'{x}-06-30' for x in range(1970, 2021)])
#print (r)

for x in ['2017-07-01','2017-07-02','2018-06-30','2019-02-19','2019-08-19']:
    out = (r[r.searchsorted(pd.Timestamp(x))] + pd.Timedelta(1, 'd')).year
    print (out)
2018
2018
2018
2019
2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a sample dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(
    dates=[pd.datetime(2018, 6, 1), pd.datetime(2018, 7, 1), pd.datetime(2018, 7, 2)],
    values=[0]*3
))

       dates  values
0 2018-06-01       0
1 2018-07-01       0
2 2018-07-02       0
```

... I have used [`pd.Grouper()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to group these down to date starting July 1st, where the key is `AS-JUL` i.e. 'annual-starting July'

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='AS-JUL', key='dates')).count()
            values
            values
dates             
2017-07-01       1
2018-07-01       2
```

You can see here that `2018-07-01` remains as `2018-07-01` after the operation